# groovy method calling with expando

Tags: groovy

I'm not sure if this is possible, so I have this method

```
callMeMethod(String param1)
```

and I want to call the method like

```
param1.callMeMethod()
```

But I am getting an error when I tried doing this

```
Unhandled Error: No signature of method: java.lang.String.callMeMethod() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Comment: The question is unclear, can you please elaborate possibly enclosing an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but you would have to add it to the metaClass of the param (String in the example you provided).
A way you could accomplish this is below.

```
String.metaClass.callMeMethod = {-> println "function code can go here"}
String param1 = "meParam"
param1.callMeMethod()

output-> function code can go here
```

I would also look at  [Category](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Category.html)

or [traits](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-traits.html) as alternatives that might be a better fit